# List.fold_left "This expression has type 'a list but an expression was expected of type 'b*'c*'d

Tags: ocaml, fold

Really confused about this one, I normally use the fold function with no problem but now I can't seem to make it work for some reason and I cannot find why.

```
L.fold_left(fun (a,b,c) acc -> if !x != 9 then (x:= !x+1; (a,b,c)::acc)else acc) list[];;
```

I also tried just doing 1::acc but it doesn't work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just take care in the oder of the argument : fold_left expect a function where the first argument is the accumulator (... somewhat the accumulator is the "left" argument), whereas fold_right expects a function where the accumulator is the second (... the accumulator is on the right). 
So just write `fun acc (a,b,c)` instead of `fun (a,b,c)` acc and your code will compile.